# Mass transit Consumer with nested generics

Tags: c#, masstransit

Hit a brick wall with mass transit

We’ve got a wrapper class

```
Public class MyMessage<T> {
Public int Id {get; set;}
Public T Payload {get;set;}
}
```

We’ve now written IConsumer which implemented the interface via

```
IConsumer<MyMessage<MyPayload>>
```

We try and register this on a specific subscription and it says

‘The consumer type was not found. … parameter T

Comment: Post the code showing how you are configuring the consumer with MassTransit